# How to keep secrets as part of configmap in kubernetes?

Tags: configuration, kubernetes

I have a config map which creates a config file to my application.

The structure is as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: database-configmap
data:
  config: |
   dbport=5432
   dcname=
   dbssl=false
   locktime=300
   domainuser=
   dattserverhost=localhost
   conntype=ON-PREM
   dbinstance=
   dattusessl=false
   dbpwd=VrjvBguQ
   iisport=80
   docountupgrade=false
   doreportupgrade=false
   dbname=dattdatabase
   dattuseiis=false
   dbtype=POSTGRESQL
   dbusername=postg
   dbserver=tgres.database.azure.com
   domainpwd=
```

Complete file will be dumped to a properties file so the application would use that.

Is there anyway to save some properties (like dbusername,dbpassword) in it as a kubernetes secret and when the deployment pods are created,  these secrets and configmap will be merged to the properties file?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't.

`Secrets` and `ConfigMaps` are different objects. `Secrets` are obfuscated with a Base64 encoding and should be used for confidential data while `ConfigMaps` are used for non-confidential data.

You should make separate objects for confidential and non-confidential data and than use them in your `Deployment`. You can modify your `Deployment` to use both `Secrets` and `ConfigMaps`, for example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: envtest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: envtest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: envtest
        image: gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/envtest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: LANGUAGE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: language
              key: LANGUAGE
        - name: API_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: apikey
              key: API_KEY
```

There are also different ways of using both `Secrets` and `ConfigMaps`. For more details, see the sources below:

- [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)
- [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)
- [Kubernetes ConfigMaps and Secrets](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b)
- [An Introduction to Kubernetes Secrets and ConfigMaps](https://opensource.com/article/19/6/introduction-kubernetes-secrets-and-configmaps)

Comment: the application configuration is saved to the properties file inside the container.Can we update the part of the configuration inside it with configmap and remaining part with secrets. We just need the username and password part of database to be set like that

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach.

Comment: can you suggest how to do that, because i wasn't able to merge to a single file both secrets and configmap

Comment: Hello @uday. It would be better if you post a separate question for that. Show your configs, what you have tried and what would you like to achieve. That way it's more clear for the community and we don't mix multiple topics/tasks in one question.

Comment: But that is the main topic of the question. to keep secrets as part of the configmap

Comment: Yes, and this topic was already covered as you shouldn't try to do it that way. That -1 for your question is not from me but it shows that you are asking for something that you should not do. The second issue is: how to configure a `deployment` to use both `secrets and `configmaps` and to get a good answer for that you should ask a separate question showing your configs and explaining the use case instead of mixing it all together here as this is not how SO and SF are supposed to work. Trust me and take my honest advice :)

Comment: The above configmap sample only database password(dbpwd) part we will keep in secrets, everything is in configmap only. So, how to link this in the configmap final file